# How can I store my result in tuple in Python

Tags: python, string, tuples, character

> Write a function called word_freq(text) which takes one string
> argument. This string will not have any punctuation. Perform a count
> of the number of 'n' character words in this string and return a list
> of tuples of the form[(n, count), (n-1, count) ...] in descending
> order of the counts. For example:
>
> Example: word_freq('a aaa a aaaa')
>
> Result: [(4, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2)]
>
> Note: that this does not show anything for the 2 character words. str1
> = 'a aaa a aaa' str.split(str1) str.count(str1)
>
> ## def word_freq(str): Python code to find frequency of each word
>
> I tried this
> text = 'a aaa a aaaa'
> def word_freq(str):
> tuple = ()
> count = {}
> for x in str:
> if x in count.keys():
> count[x] += 1
> else:
> count[x] = 1
> print(count)
> def count_letters(word):
> char = "a"
> count = 0
> for c in word:
> if char == c:
> count += 1
> return count
> word_freq(text)

Comment: you've tried it, and what was the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to solve the given question but wasn't able to perform count for each letter in the character words in string

Answer (score 2):

The code below does what you want. Now I'll explain how it works. before anything, we will make a dictionary called "WC" which will hold the count of each n-character-word in our sentence. now we start. first of all, it receives a string from user. then it takes the string and using split(), it turns the string into a LIST of words. then for each word it checks its length, if it is 2, it ignores it. otherwise, it will add 1 to the count of that n-character word in our dictionary.
after every word is checked, we use wc.items() to turn our dictionary into a list of tuples. Each element in the list is a tuple that contains data for each word. each tuple has 2 elements. the first is number of charatcers of each word and the second element is the number of times it existed in the sentence. with that out of the way, Now all we need is to do is sort this list based on the character counts in reverse (from high char count to low char count). we do that using the sorted function. we sort based on x[0] which means the first element of each tuple which is the character count for each word. Finally, we return this list of tuples. You can print it.
if anything is unclear, let me know. also, you can put print() statements at every line so you can better understand what is happening.
here's the code, I hope it helps:

```
inp = input("Enter your text: ")
def word_count(inp_str):
    wc = {}
    for item in inp_str.strip().split():
        if len(item) == 2:
            continue

        wc[len(item)] = wc.get(len(item), 0) + 1

    return sorted(wc.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse = True)

print(word_count(inp))
```